# Цвет html текста в редакторе VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

День добрый. Подскажите, хочу изменить цвет текста (который находится между тегами) в документе .html.

Пример: <див> Текст <див>. Я хочу чтобы слово Текст был красного цвета, как это сделать? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для изменения стиля оформления независимо от выбранной темы добавьте в файл `settings.json`:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "text.html",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#ff0000"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Хотя правильнее будет переопределять цвета указывая конкретную тему, например `Default Light+`:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Light+]": {
      "textMateRules": [
        {
          "scope": "text.html",
          "settings": {
            "foreground": "#ff0000"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Что-бы узнать название выделяемого элемента (или `scope`) нажимаем в VS Code комбинацию <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (или просто <kbd>F1</kbd>), вводим команду `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` и выбираем мышкой нужный элемент, после чего откроется окошко с подробной информацией об элементе, и внизу будут перечислены все примененные к элементу имена scop'ов.

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но JSX разметка не меняет цвет, есть что то вроди  text.jsx ?

Comment: Можно попробовать `meta.jsx.children.js`. А вообще узнать `scope` можно командой `Developer: inspect TM scopes`.

Comment: Да, я нашел, просто покапавшись в theme (искал через ctrl-f jsx).
meta.jsx.children - отвечает за цвет. 
Спасибо за ответ!